# Adding gettext comments to Twig templates?

Tags: twig

Looking over [the documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/i18n.html) I couldn't find any mention of it, so I'll ask: Does the Twig i18n extension support embedded comments, which can be extracted via gettext? In other words, is there an equivalent Twig syntax for this:

```php
/// TRANSLATORS: Please leave %s as it is, because it is needed by the program.
/// Thank you for contributing to this project.
printf(_("My name is %s."), $myName);
```

Which will be extractable as:

```gettext
#. TRANSLATORS: Please leave %s as it is, because it is needed by the program.
#. Thank you for contributing to this project.
msgid "My name is %s."
msgstr ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there didn't appear to be any facility for this, in the meantime I have written an extension for it: [Twig_Extension_Gettext](https://github.com/deceze/Twig-extensions/blob/master/doc/gettext.rst). It adds many missing gettext features, including a native template parser which supports extractable comments.